# Apache2 virtual host load server documentroot

Tags: server, apache2

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 VPS and installed apache2 there and also PHP7, fail2ban and other things.

I also set up a VirtualHost for my domain (XXXXX.XX) a link it into /var/www/html/twido-demo but the site loads content from /var/www/html.

What did I wrong?

**File /etc/apache2/sites-available/twido.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName XXXXX.XX
   ServerAlias www.XXXXX.XX

   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/twido-demo

    <Directory /var/www/html/twido-demo>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myproject-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myproject-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**File /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

XX.2.241.236 XXXXX.XX
```

[Image - Content of folder which should load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKVV5.png)

Can you see a mistake in there?

Comment: Did you enable your site config, twido after creating the site?  Did you restart apache after enabling you site?

Comment: Yes, I run:
sudo a2ensite twido.conf;
sudo service apache2 restart;
and just for sure:
sudo reboot

Comment: In which access log does the browser request get logged? If not in `myproject-access.log` (where it should be), then it will be in the access log of the VirtualHost handling the request. What ServerName a/o ServerAlias are set for that VirtualHost? And just to be sure: you direct your browser to `http://XXXXX.XX/`, right? (Not http**s**, not to localhost, not to a numeric IP address.)

Comment: 1) myproject-access.log does not exist in /var/log/apache2 (${APACHE_LOG_DIR}), access.log and access.log.1 are empty.

Comment: 2) ServerName and ServerAlias are twido.cz and www.twido.cz. I am trying it like http://twido.cz

Comment: If `myproject-access.log` and `myproject-error.log` do not exist, then this VirtualHost is not running. Check the error logs and double check `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` for the presence of the conf-file.

Comment: That's weird. 1) /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/twido.conf does exist 2) Error.log is empty 3) When I run "a2dissite" it puts "Your choices are: twido", so I think it's running..